# Расшифруйте условие регенерации тюпла

Tags: python-3.x

Объясните пожалуйста, что значит этот кусочек кода. Вроде по отдельности всё знакомо, но воедино соединить не могу:((

`next(( x for x in string if string.lower().count(x.lower())==1), '')`

Comment: это способ взять один элемент из набора подходящий под условие поиска. когда мы не можем искать напрямую, потому что критерий поиска опирается на какое-то свойство объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам генератор формирует последовательность тех символов, которых в строке по одному, а `next` возвращает первый элемент последовательности или пустую строку, если последовательность пуста.